# ObjectInputStream Android

Tags: android, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have some trouble with the ObjectInputStream in an little android project. On my Laptop I have a Server running, which respondes an int to a String, which comes from my client (running on my andoid device).

Here is my Server:

```
ServerSocket socketmaker = new ServerSocket(30001);
Socket tSocket = socketmaker.accept();

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(tSocket.getInputStream());
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(tSocket.getOutputStream());
String text = "";
int hashed = 0;

text = (String) in.readObject();
System.out.print("The Client asks with \""+text+"\"");
hashed = hash(text);
out.writeUTF(String.valueOf(hashed));
System.out.print(" and we answer with the hash \""+hashed+"\"\n");

out.close();
in.close();
tSocket.close();
```

And here comes the app:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String server = host.getText().toString();
    int portNr = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());

    try {
        Socket tSocket = new Socket(server, portNr);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(tSocket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(tSocket.getInputStream());
        String text = content.getText().toString(); 

        out.writeObject(text);
        int re = Integer.parseInt(in.readUTF());
        Toast.makeText(ClientActivity.this, re, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        out.close();
        in.close();
        tSocket.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //print ex here...
    }
}
```

host, port, conent are EditText's and allow the client to put in the serverinfo.

I run the server on a console and it receives the text from the client and prints out:

```
The Client asks with "test" and we answer with the hash "48"
```

But then the app closes with an error.
So the error has to be with the server sending the int and the app receiving it.But I also set the permissions in the Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I also tried it with:

```
writeObject(int)    - Integer.parseInt(readObject())
writeObject(String) - readObject()
writeInt(int)       - readInt()
```

but none of them worked.

So please help me, and excuse my bad english (non native).
Thanks

Comment: Please post the logcat of the error.

Comment: I'm debugging the app on my Nexus 5, by uploading the .apk file to my Drive and installing it on the smartphone. So I don't know how LogCat could export its errors to a file. It's not possible to run an emulator on my Laptop, cause it's graphics card is too shitty. And other ideas?